# UITextField nil on button click, but works onchange

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm getting the following error on button click

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**following is the code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var UserId: UITextField!{
    didSet{
        UserId.setBottomBorder()
        UserId.delegate = self
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!{
    didSet{
        Password.setBottomBorder()
        Password.delegate = self
    }
}

@IBAction func logincta(_ sender: Any) {
           guard let _ = UserId.text, UserId.text?.characters.count != 0 else {
        print("test")
        return
    }

}
```

but works fine in  the following onchange code

```
@IBAction func UserIdChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserId.text == "" {
        UserId.setBottomBorder()
    }
    else{
    UserId.setPurpleBottomBorder()
    }
}

@IBAction func PasswordChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if Password.text == "" {
        Password.setBottomBorder()
    }
    else{
        Password.setPurpleBottomBorder()
    }
}
```

i wonder how it worked in onchange event "if UserId.text == ""  but not in button click

Comment: Can you please show your `setBottomBorder` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: check your textfield outlet reference

Comment: but if the textfield reference is wrong it shouldn't work on change event.... but it works fine on that.... only on button click i get the error

Comment: @iPeter following is the code
func setBottomBorder(){
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:193/255 , green:193/255 , blue:193/255 , alpha:100 ).cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }

Comment: Don't do in didSet of UITextField, viewDidLoad is the right place to work with IBOutlets.

Comment: Please share your full code. I need to to have a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it seems to work...

Anyway maybe try to use the guard in this way:

```
guard let numOfChars = UserId?.text?.count, numOfChars != 0 else {
        print("test")
        return
    }
```